# Is there a way to auto-generate models for OrmLite using .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am making the assumption that the T4 templates still are not supported in .Net Core.  Based on the articles I've read, I do not see any way to make them work.  I have a large database schema that I'd like to procedurally generate my models from.  Is there an alternative method for generating the models for ServiceStack's OrmLite or is there a hacky way to get the T4 to run on .Net Core?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'd personally use code-first models where possible, the most obvious solution would be to generate the models in a .NET Framework project then use the generated models in your .NET Core project.

Comment: I think that's the conclusion I'm leaning towards.  Having close to 200 models, auto-generating them will save some time. Moving forward we'll create the models code-first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

T4 Templates do work in .NET core. [T4Executer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TimMaes.ttexecuter) adds support to run them on every build (before or after build event).